# Bessel Functions Proof

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would I even begin to start proving the following?

[image]

After looking at Frobenius' method and the Rieman P-equation, I started delving into the derivation of Bessel's/Legendre's functions, and I understand the theory regarding what's going on.  However, for proving stuff like that above, I'm either completely lost, or I don't have sufficient resources to look into doing this.  Could someone help me with a proof like this, or could you point towards some useful resources for proving things like this?  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What differential equation do the $J_n$ satisfy?

Comment: @RonGordon They satisfy Bessel's differential equation as found here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html but with z as the independent variable (since we are in the complex domain)

Comment: OK, perhaps you could apply the differential operator of the equation to the integral here and see what happens.

Comment: @RonGordon Hmmmmm, I suppose that would work.  So, the main idea would be to substitute this form the J into the differential equation and see that it's satisfied?  That seems pretty straightforward, but applying the differential operators might be a bit tricky.

Comment: @RonGordon I just worked through that exercise, and I can't seem to make it satisfy the differential equation =/.  Is there some special relation which I'm missing?

Comment: Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: I worked through it, too, and I am ashamed to say that I did not finish it off.  Perhaps you can post what you've done and we can see where we need to go.

Comment: Use the identity here: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion for $\sin(z\cos\theta)$, and apply the orthogonality of cosines of the form $\cos(n\theta), \cos([2n-1]\theta)$ on the interval $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}] $.

Comment: @Bitrex Thank you for the response; that totally makes sense too!  However, is it justified to take the integral inside that sum?  What kind of property must I satisfy for that; does it have to be uniformly convergent?

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with

$\sin (z\sin \theta)=2\sum_{0}^{\infty}J_{2n+1}(z)\sin (2n+1)\theta $

Replace $\theta$ with $\pi/2 -\phi $,

substituting $\lambda=2n+1$ so $n=(\lambda-1)/2$ so that $\lambda$ is always odd,

multiplying both sides by $\cos (\lambda\phi)$ and integrate from $0$ to $\pi$ :

$2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos (\lambda\phi)\sin (z\cos \phi)d\phi=(-1)^{(\lambda-1)/2}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos (\lambda\phi)2\sum_{0}^{\infty}J_{\lambda}(z)\cos (\lambda\phi) d\phi $

and because $1/(-1)^{(\lambda-1)/2} = (-1)^{(\lambda-1)/2}$

$(-1)^{(\lambda-1)/2}2/\pi\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos (\lambda\phi)\sin (z\cos \theta)d\phi=J_{\lambda}(z) $

$\lambda$ odd

because $\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos (\lambda\phi)^2 d\phi =\pi/2$

Comment: @wuyudi, please don't edit dozens of old questions. That bumps new questions off the front page. Do three or four edits a day, please.